# Chrome: className attribute changing not working with GWT

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom, gwt

I have a site written in GWT. I need to change style of some element by clicking on this element. I'm using code like this:

```
image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  ...............
        Element element = ((Image) event.getSource()).getElement();
        element.setClassName("new_css_class_to_be_applied");
       }
```

'setClassName' GWT function uses className JavaScript property to operate with class:

```
   public final native void setClassName(String className) /*-{
       this.className = className;
    }-*/;
```

This code changes a class name of element (I can see the new class name in the DOM inspector) but styles from the class do not apply to the element.

This problem appears only in Chrome browser on Windows, with IE  and Firefox it works well.

If I move folder with Chrome local settings (  C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\ ) this problem disappears and style changing starts working correctly. But if I return back previous chrome settings folder this code doesn't work again. I have no any specific settings or plugins in Chrome, everything is default.

It seems to be a bug in the Chrome browser but I don't find concrete preconditions how to reproduce it. I googled but didn't find the same problems and resolutions.

Could anybody advice me any workaround for the problem?

UPD. It was a problem with AdBlock Chrome extension. I disabled it and the problem disappeared.More details: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377913

Comment: As it really looks like a Chrome bug, I'd suggest filing an issue at https://crbug.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a simple html document without any JS library not GWT app and execute something like:

```
 document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

If the problem persists open an issue to chrome.

Also you can try the same in your GWT app using the developer console and see if it happens.

If you can demonstrate a procedure which can be repeatable by anyone for making it happe only in GWT open an issue in the GWT site.